# Actions have different operation time in reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I would like to apply reinforcement learning method to a complicated problem which has a lot of action. And each action also has a different operating time. It means the time to switch to the next state is different for each action. I don't know how to design this experiment. Do I need to regard operation time as the part of state? Or I don't need to consider this?

Answer (score 1):

You could express reinforcement in terms of time. Each time your agent completes an action, give it a negative reinforcement proportional to the amount of time it took. When your agent solves the problem, give it a positive reinforcement proportional to the amount of time the problem is worth.